# telethon getting input from message

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

i'm making a bot and i need to get an input from message, and i have no idea how to do it.

**the chat should look like this.**

```
bot: send x

me: x

bot: send y

me: y
```

and saving it in a csv file.

this is the code now:

```
bot.on(events.CallbackQuery)
async def handler(event):
    if event.data == b"1":  
        await event.respond("x")
        ##code
        await event.respond("x")
        ##code
        await event.respond("x")
```

Answer (score 0):

`CallbackQuery` events occur when an inline button is pressed. If you want to handle incoming messages, you have to use `events.NewMessage`:

```py
@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def handler(event):
    if event.text.startswith('send '):
        send_what = event.text[len('send '):]
        await event.respond(send_what)
```

See also the documentation page on updates https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/basic/updates.html.